# How to improve system that saves div dimensions to css with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, save

Warning: I'm not a good person to explain things, my english isn't perfect and I'm a bit noob with php, javascript and jquery. If you think you can handle that, keep reading.

So, I have this small system where you can add divs to a website, drag them and scale them. This is easy with jquery. However I'm trying to save the changes to css and html files, so next time you open the page it would be just like you edited it to be.

It isn't ready yet, but I know it is possible to do it. However before completing it, I would like to know if anyone has suggestions how to make it more simple or better in any way.

I'll explain how it works now:

User adds few divs, scales and drags them around. (JQuery UI). When the user clicks a button that saves the changes, system checks how many child elements the main container has (all the user-created divs are children of the main container). Now the system loops all the child elements and gets their dimensions (`width`, `height`, `left`, `right`) into array like this `[0]="200,300,500,500"`. When the loop is complete, system joins the array into a string, where different elements are separated with semicolon.

System posts the string with `$.ajax()` and uses php file to read it, this is what happens in the php file:

1. php parses the string it got via post, into array like this

   ```
   [0]="200,300,500,500"
   ```
2. now it loops through the content of the array, parsing each string into 4 variables

   ```
   $width = 200;
   $height = 300;
   $left = 500;
   $top = 500;
   ```
3. Now the system puts these values into another array as string and adds the css code to the string. So this new array looks like this

   ```
   [0] = "#div0{width:200px;height:300px;left:500px;top:500px;}."
   ```
4. Once the array is complete, system implodes it into a string, deletes the old `customstyle.css` file and writes the string into new `customstyle.css` file.

Didn't include the creation of custom html file in this, but it's simply done by checking how many values the array made of post data has, then creating equal amount of divs into html file where each div has id of "div(number)".

When the page loads, php includes custom css and html files. Goal is to have index page that doesn't require javascript and is xhtml valid with simple styling, other page that is for editing and requires javascript ofcourse.

I think this system is far too complicated, there's too many arrays etc. But I don't know how to make it more simple :)

I was thinking of creating the whole style string with javascript at start and posting it to php as a whole, then just writing it to stylesheet as it is. But it's a lot bigger string than now and posting it wouldn't be so effective. (Not that it would matter since I'm the only one trying the system, but it doesn't feel right :P)

Answer (score 1):

The save button could assemble a json object with a collection of all the divs. It offers many advantages over using strings and can easily be read by php.

On the php side, write a class for the custom element. It will help readability and also allow you to assemble your data in a more logical manner. Class could be as simple as this

```
class CustomElement{
    public $height;
    public $width;
    public $leftPos;
    public $rightPos;
    private $elmentName;

    public function __construct($name){
       $this->elementName = $name
    }
}
```

Now whenever you want to deal with a new custom element you can do

```
$curElement = new CustomElement("div2");
$curElement->height = 600;
$curElement->width = 800;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for cookies. Basically you save the dimension state to cookies ([here's a link to Quirksmode describing using cookies in Javascript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)). On page load, you try to retrieve the dimension state from cookies with javascript and apply it to your elements. You can filter them with jQuery by html (css) classes so it's a simple task.

If you do it right, the user won't notice anything.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds good, but actually I was looking for a way to actually store the dimensions. Think of this as a very simple and useless website editor, where the author of the site can edit the page and everybody who visit the page see it how author saved it.

Comment: Where it's saved is not the issue. Asker is trying to figure out a better design to avoid "too many arrays".

Comment: Actually I asked the question and tried to correct it with the comment :) And as said, I'd like to have it stored on the server, rather than in a cookie. I'm looking for better way of doing what the system is doing now. Saving div sizes and positions to css and html files.